# Is the Antiderivative of an Elementary Function Being Nonelementary Generic?

Tags: soft-question, elementary-functions, differential-algebra

Many [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), like [$e^{-x^2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and [$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) have antiderivatives that are are nonelementary; is this property [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property)? That is, does the set of all elementary functions whose antiderivatives are nonelementary form residual (or second category) subset (that is, the complement of a [meager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) or first category subset) of the elementary functions (with some version of the compact-open topology on them, presumably: the elementary functions don't all share a common domain)?

On a related (but still very basic) note, what would be a catch-all term for the collection of all elementary and nonementary functions taken together as one set? "Functions of a real (or complex) variable"?

$\underline{\text{Edit 1}}$: I guess [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) is a partial answer, at least. It appears to yield that the elementary functions whose antiderivatives are elementary are emphatically a meager set, but if I could just get someone who is much more experienced at this game to confirm that for me in simple terms that will be easy for me to understand, I would be most appreciative.

$\underline{\text{Edit 2}}$: In response to an answer from Robert Israel below, I changed the question from asking if the elementary functions whose antiderivatives are nonelementary form an open, dense subset to asking if they form a residual set.

$\underline{\text{Aside}}$: Why isn't Liouville's Theorem part of a standard graduate curriculum for those who want to go on to teach calculus? In what standard (graduate or undergraduate) course would one typically encounter Liouville's Theorem? What book would be a reference for differential algebras and Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: One might note that the elementary functions are a vector space and the ones with elementary anti-derivatives are a strict subspace thereof. (And, if you're careful, a subspace with infinite codimension). In some (standard, but rather uninteresting) sense, this means that most functions don't have elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks, @MiloBrandt ! ("Strict subspace" meaning "proper subspace", of course)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks so much again for the reply! I really appreciate it! Unfortunately, the answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496436/construct-dense-subspace-of-codimension-n-for-all-n appears to imply that a subspace can be proper and of infinite codimension and dense (Take the union $W$ of all the spaces $X_n$ in the answer). So, being a proper subspace (even of infinite codimension) does not appear to necessarily imply meager.

Comment: Residual in what topology?  Unless you have somehow a topology where the elementary functions are complete?  Otherwise I would guess the space of elementary functions is of first category in itself...

Comment: A topology on the differential algebra of functions of a real variable? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29#Definitions I'm not sure myself, which topology to use was a part of my question, I'm a little new at this game myself

Answer (score 3):

Not open, no.  Polynomials are dense in the compact-open topology on continuous functions on an interval (or a disk in the complex plane), and they always have elementary antiderivatives.

Comment: (Off-topic: Is this *the* Robert Israel [http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=2251729&tstart=0 among oher things]? Wow, thanks for the reply!)

Comment: Of course, Stone-Weierstrass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem applies; thanks so much

Comment: Yes, I am *that* Robert Israel.

Comment: (I apologize that this question is basic.) So, putting aside the notion of elementary/nonelementary and just looking at W, the set of polynomials, in V,  $C^1(I)$/$C^n(I)$/$C^{\infty}(I)$, on the one hand, by Milo Brandt's comment, W is a proper subspace subspace of V (with infinite codimension, in fact), while on the other hand, by Robert Israel's comment, V is dense in W.

(cont)

Comment: Intuitively, these two notions don't make sense together: if V were an inner product space, for instance, one could just take v in V with <v|p> = 0 for all p in W, take $k \in \mathbb{R}$ with $k>0$, and take B(v,k/2); that should contain no points of W - but W is dense in V! This idea should work for any inner product one could put on V which induces the compact-open topology on V - but, of course, it can't work for any of them (meaning no inner product on V can induce the compact-open topology on V?) since W is dense in V by Stone-Weierstrass. (cont)

Comment: Thanks in any assistance you can provide.

Comment: (The v in V with <v|p> = 0 for all p in W in the above should have $v \ne 0$, of course :/ )

Comment: If $W$ is dense in an inner product space $V$, there is no nonzero $v \in V$ with $\langle v | p \rangle = 0$ for all $p \in W$.  Only closed subspaces can have nontrivial orthogonal complements.

Comment: Thanks; I never took a course in Functional Analysis and I don't recall going over closed subspaces of Hilbert/infinite-dimensional inner product spaces in Real Analysis - this http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M645/BasicHS.pdf helped with the confusion.

So, elementary functions with nonelementary antiderivatives are definitely not an open, dense subset of all elementary functions; thanks, I really appreciate the help