# Show that if the open ball of normed vector space $E$ is precompact, then $\mathrm{dim}(E)<\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Show that if the open ball of normed vector space $E$ is precompact, then $\mathrm{dim}(E)<\infty$.

**Remark:** The most common proof in the functional analysis books is the one found in this [link](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=d3LrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=ball+is+precompact+then+space+is+finite+dimensional++Elements+of+functional+analysis&source=bl&ots=GkXuGfqLkX&sig=5kRmmIoMt52J_ZDBWoFnxytle9Y&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCqKqglJnXAhUG4yYKHXG7BIkQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=ball%20is%20precompact%20then%20space%20is%20finite%20dimensional%20%20Elements%20of%20functional%20analysis&f=false). My intention is to carry out another proof using the fact that in ***all infinite dimensional vector normed space there is a  non-continuous linear form***.

**My attepmt:** We suppose that $E$ is infinite dimensional and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is non-continuous linear form ($\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), an idea of the proof of the existence of this function can be found in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2496463).

Since $f$ is discontinuous function then for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_{n}\in E$ such that $\left\|x_{n}\right\|=1$ and $|f(x_{n})|>n$. Let $M_{n}=\mathrm{span}\left\{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right\}$, since $M_{n}$ is finite dimensional, then $M_{n}$ is reflexive and $\left.f_{n}\right|_{M_{n}}$ is bounded, let $\alpha_{n}=\left\|\left.f_{n}\right|_{M_{n}}\right\|$.

By Hahn-Banach theorem and the fact that $M_{n}$ is reflexive we can choose $y_{n}\in M_{n}$ such that $\left\|y_{n}\right\|=1$ and  $|f(y_{n})|=\alpha_{n}$.

Therefore, $\left\{y_{n}\right\}\subseteq \overline{B_{1}(0)}$, **If I can prove that $\left\{y_{n}\right\}$ does not have convergent subsequences or that it does not have Cauchy subsequences then the proof will have ended** because $\overline{B_{1}(0)}$ would not be compact, which implies that $B_{1}(0)$ would not be precompact, which is a contradiction.

**The problem:** I have not been able to demonstrate the final part of my proof proposal, although I'm not sure it's true either.

Comment: Not that it affects your proof, but I think both of your links are to user profiles, not answers.

Comment: @MichaelLee I already corrected the problem.